# Adding viewcontroller elements to another scrollview

Tags: objective-c

I have a `ViewController` called Tag that has labels and photos I need to recreate on another `viewcontroller` called "Task" with a `scrollview`. I've added these by saying:

Task.m

```
 - (void)loadFromNib {
Tag *tag = [[Tag alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:tag.imageView3];
    [scroll addSubview:tag.imageView3];
```

The image only loads when it's not added to the scrollview.

Comment: Are u sure your scrollView is working? I am not sure but you can try add also [self.view addsubview:scroll];

Comment: Should be working. I connected it and added  scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 960);